# My var value doesn't update on first "click"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, boolean, onclicklistener

I have the next code:

```
private fun conectarProfesor() {

      databaseReference.child("User").orderByChild("correo").equalTo(correoEditText.text.toString()).addValueEventListener(object :
            ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Failed to load post.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                existe = false
                listaNombresProfesores.clear()

                for (ListaProfesores in dataSnapshot.children) {


                    var profesor = ListaProfesores.getValue(User::class.java)
                    System.out.println(profesor!!.tipo)
                    if (profesor!!.tipo == "profesor") {
                        System.out.println("TRUEEE")  **->>> THIS WORKS!!!**
                        existe = true
                    }
                    else{
                        existe = false
                    }
                }
            }
        })

    }
```

Then, I evaluate the var "existe"...  and  i dont know why the correct value has one click delay,

"System.out.println("TRUEEE")" is working, but the value only is updated in the next click.

Ty!

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over children in the dataSnapshot:

```
                for (ListaProfesores in dataSnapshot.children) {


                var profesor = ListaProfesores.getValue(User::class.java)
                System.out.println(profesor!!.tipo)
                if (profesor!!.tipo == "profesor") {
                    System.out.println("TRUEEE")  **->>> THIS WORKS!!!**
                    existe = true
                }
                else{
                    existe = false
                }
            }
```

I suspect, there might be a case, where in the last iteration `profesor!!.tipo != "profesor"` and therefore it would set `existe` to `false`.

What could work, if you would break out of a for loop as soon as your condition is satisfied and you set `existe` to `true`.

```
                for (ListaProfesores in dataSnapshot.children) {


                var profesor = ListaProfesores.getValue(User::class.java)
                System.out.println(profesor!!.tipo)
                if (profesor!!.tipo == "profesor") {
                    System.out.println("TRUEEE")  **->>> THIS WORKS!!!**
                    existe = true
                    break
                }
                else{
                    existe = false
                }
            }
```

Comment: Ty for the answer, but i think the problem is delay in onDataChange... the part of code where I evaluate the var is after and it is executed before in runtime... finally I have solved the problem.